# Angular template doesn't render data from controller

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm setting up an Angular JS app to consume a Django REST API, and I'm stuck on the rendering of data.
I already asked another question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043842/resolved-false-in-angular-js-response)), but the solution that I've been given doesn't work.

I was wondering that maybe there is something wrong in the API view, could it be a problem when trying to render the data from the Angular controller?

Anyway, this is my Angular app + template (edited as suggested in the other stackoverflow question)

base.html

```
<body ng-app="schoolApp" ng-controller="schoolCtrl as vm">
    <p>Hello {{vm.name}}!</p>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Floor</th>
                    <th>Academic year</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="classroom in vm.classrooms">
                    <td>{{classroom.classroom}}</td>
                    <td>{{classroom.school.school_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{classroom.floor}}</td>
                    <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var schoolApp = angular.module('schoolApp', ['ngResource']);

schoolApp.factory('Classroom', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/classrooms/?format=json', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    });
}]);

schoolApp.controller('schoolCtrl', function($scope, Classroom) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'World';
   Classroom.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
     console.log('Success: '+JSON.stringify(data));
     vm.classrooms = data;

   }, function (reason) {
     console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(reason));
   });
});
```

I was thinking that maybe there is some problem on the view, so here's the REST API view

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'school_app/base.html'

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer


class ClassroomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Classroom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassroomSerializer
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

This is what I get

[image]

Data on the console: yes.
Data on the tables: no.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `controllerAs` syntax, you have binded all data to controller context. So you could get data on view using its alias like `vm.classrooms`

```
<tr ng-repeat="classroom in vm.classrooms">
```

Comment: Thank you, that was my omission (the guy that gave me the solution on the other question specified that). However, it's not working anyway. I'm updating the question to show a screenshot of what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to output in the html the content of the variable vm.classrooms.

You can do it with

```
<pre>{{vm.classrooms|json}}</pre>
```

It seems to me that you are not binding correctly the variables inside the table,

i can't see it clearly in the picture, it can be {{ classroom.school.academic_year }} ??

Comment: The variables are binded correctly, given that I tried to build an Angular app alone with hardcoded Json data (taken from the Django REST data), and the tables are filled correctly. Anyway, I'm trying that, but I get an error: "Invalid filter: 'json'"

Comment: I do not understand the error, [jsonfilter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) is part of angular built in filters.

Comment: Any way if you have tried with harcoded data and it works, the problem is in the call back from the query , have you checked what data is.

Comment: I've tried without the filter, and the template doesn't receive the data. What do you mean with "what data is"? It's json data... is this your doubt?

Comment: Apologize my english is not as good as i would like. I mean in your callback function you have a variable called data, which you already are showing in the console in your post, so forget my comment.

Comment: Does {{ vm.name }} output 'World'?

Comment: Nope. As you can see in the screenshot, the output is "Hello !"